# set value on dropdown to be empty string conditionaly, depending on the value od another dropdown in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to solve this for days now, I don't know what is causing this behaviour, but hope that someone can help me. I have two dropdowns, when certain value is chosen on the first dropdown, I want to set the state of the second dropdown to be empty string.
So far I have this function:

```
const handleChangeSteps = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, task_type: e.value });
      if (e.value === "Steps") {
      setValues({ ...values, reward_distributor_id: "" });
      setIsDisabled(true) // I am using this to empty the value of the reward_distributor_id dropdown //;
    } else {
      setIsDisabled(false);
    }
};
```

When the value of task_type is "Steps", I want reward_distributor_id to be empty. Whit this implementation, it is deleting reward_distributor_id but after that, I can not change the value of task_type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share all the code of the component so we can understand where states and isDisabled is used.

I think you should try to trigger only one setValues in your handleChange, because the component don't rerender and actualise values when you call it a second times. Does something like this works ? :

```
const handleChangeSteps = (e) => {
if (e.value === "Steps") {
  setValues({ ...values, task_type: e.value, reward_distributor_id: "" });
  setIsDisabled(true) 
} else {
  setValues({ ...values, task_type: e.value });
  setIsDisabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfect! I really had no idea about this, and even if I had spend three more days, I wouldn't solve it :D. Thank you so much for your help! isDisabled actually I am using to disable reward_distributor_id dropdown, when the value of task_type is steps, and it is wokring fine, I only wrote it in this function because I needed to send a bollean as an atribute.